# How to display an image when the user clicks a detail button in a tableview. iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

I know that this question may be asked before , but I was unable to find it online . I just wanted to know that how can I display a POP UP image OR TEXT when the user clicks on the detail button on a tableview .
[image: SIMULATOR IMAGE]

Thank you guys .

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html

Comment: How about showing a new ViewController using Modal Segue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to implement the [delegate method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:):
`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

When that method is called, present a modal view controller or alert view to get the popup.